# How to save the dynamic input data in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm having a trouble in saving the data from vuejs to Laravel controller, I can successfully add a new input field but can't save the data to database

**kidComponent.vue**

```
<div class="pb-3">
    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">
        Number of Kids: <button @click="addNewChild"><i class="fa fa-list -ic2"></i></button>
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="columns pl-3" v-for="(kid, index) in kids" :key=" 'index' + index">
    <div class="column is-4">
        <b-field label="Name">
            <b-input v-model="kid.fullname" rounded></b-input>
        </b-field>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-4">
        <b-field label="Birthday">
            <b-datepicker v-model="kid.birthdate" rounded></b-datepicker>
        </b-field>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-4">
        <b-field label="Age">
            <b-input type="number" v-model="kid.age" rounded></b-input>
        </b-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Vue Method**

```
addNewChild() {
   this.kids.push({ 
       fullname: '',
       age: ''
   })
}
```

**Controller**

```
$kids = Kid::create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

you will receive the kids data as an array. you have to loop through the array to insert each element of the array.

```
foreach ($request->kids as $key => $value) {
    Kid::create($value);
}
```

or if you want particularly which value goes where, you can write like

```
foreach ($request->kids as $key => $value) {
    Kid::create([
        'fullname' => $value['fullname'],
        'age' => $value['age'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: its giving me an error of "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()",

Comment: how you are sending your from data?? can you show me the form data??

Comment: axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/addKids',
    data: this.kids
})
.then(response => {
    this.data = response.data
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

Comment: im saving the data throuch click event that calling the axios

Comment: what's inside this kids variable?? isn't it an object??